# Url connection getInputStream Android Error

Tags: android, inputstream

I am trying to upload the server from an Android app. I am getting an error  with the response code 500 and the message is Internal Server Error. The conn.getInputStream will result in an exception and its message is the URL.

Below is my code, can anyone please help me to figure out what I am missing here?

```
try{
                    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            try{
                conn.setDoOutput(true);
                OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream()); 
                wr.write( data ); 
                wr.flush(); 
                Log.i("GCM","responseCode::"+conn.getResponseCode());
                Log.i("GCM","responseMsg::"+conn.getResponseMessage());
                // Get the server response 
                InputStreamReader in=new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream());
                reader = new BufferedReader(in);
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                String line = null;

                // Read Server Response
                while((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
                {
                    Log.i("GCM",line);
                    // Append server response in string
                    sb.append(line + "\n");
                }
                // Append Server Response To Content String 
                Content = sb.toString();
            }
            finally
            {
                conn.disconnect();
                try
                {
                    reader.close();
                }
                catch(Exception ex) {}
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Error = ex.getMessage();
            Log.i("GCM","MsgError:::"+Error);
        }
```

Comment: post your exception what your are getting

Comment: I am not getting anything, I just show in a toast whether the post went through or failed. Well, it fails and displays the server url.